# Create model object in django admin using save_model method

Tags: python, django

I am coming from php background so python-django is totally new to me. I am trying to insert a new record in `account_emailaddress` table from admin.py using `save_model` method , whenever a new user is created from admin section.

Following are the partial contents from `models.py`

```
class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name ='address')
    email = models.EmailField()
    verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('verified'), default=True)
    primary = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('primary'), default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'account_emailaddress'
```

From `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import admin as upstream
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import EmailAddress



class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_select_related = ( 'profile', )

    #exclude = ('username',)

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal information', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('None', {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['-date_joined']


    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.EmailAddress.save()
        obj.save()



admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

I am getting an error --

```
'User' object has no attribute 'EmailAddress'
```

------------------UPDATE 1 BEGIN---------------

From models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model, HashedPk):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name ='profile')
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=False, default="")
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField( blank=True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        #if the loggedin user is admin or user_created_by admin then create the object 
        #EmailAddress.objects.create(user=instance, email=instance.email)
```

------------------UPDATE 1 END---------------

```
#EmailAddress.objects.create(user=instance, email=instance.email)
```

The above code works but I won't be able to use it here because `allauth` app(I am using for user registration in the frontend) tries to create the same row in `account_emailaddress` table and thus create duplicate error.

Is it possible so that if the user is created by admin then create object.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find out the real property name by writing the following code `print(dir(obj))` after `save_model` function, if you cant't find it please add output to question and we can help you

Comment: Thanks @latsha I have updated the post.

Comment: in `save_model` you can check like this `if request.user.is_superuser:`

Answer (score 3):

You've defined the related_name from User to EmailAddress as `address`, so that's what you should use:

```
obj.address.save()
```

Note, even if you hadn't defined this, the default related_name is the lower-case version of the model name.

Comment: I tried but it says `User has no address`. It should work in this way.

Comment: That's telling you that the specific User you are saving has no related EmailAddress object. Did you create one? Where? Show that code.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood your question. The answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add some notes to answers. At first you can allways check the property name by just printing all properties `print(dir(obj))` if you don't want to use debuggers. If you want to permit only admin users to create that objects you can write this check `if request.user.is_superuser:`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually it's not checking if the added user is super admin or not rather checking if created_ by user is admin or not. I think I am going to this in another way. Let  the admin create user first and then confirm his email from another view.